# How to work with negative co-ordinates in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I am writing an Win Form application to draw a diagram which has negative

> coordinates (X = -1245, Y = -456).

Windows forms starts with `(0,0)` on the top left corner so my diagram goes outside of the page. and some get draw above the exiting lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: System.Drawing is quite new to me.

Comment: I think you simply need to create a conversion subroutine to convert from source coordinates to acceptable coordinates format for WinForms (positive)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See the link that Hans Passant provided. You can translate the coordinates of your drawings, positioning them where you see fit. It can be the botton-left corner, or the center of your surface/canvas/(device context). See also [About Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162466(v=vs.85).aspx) and give a look at the links in the left menu.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough points to comment and this should be a comment I hope this can resolve your issue
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372617/setting-a-c-sharp-form-to-a-negative-location). Moreover it is for the form location but as far as my little experience goes the Location for the controls will be dependent on their parent container if I am right.
Further as far as my experience goes you can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073170/1722792)

```
Point relativePos = new Point(-10, -10);
control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
control.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - control.Width + relativePos.X, this.ClientSize.Height - control.Height + relativePos.Y);
```

Comment: I recommend turning this into an answer by providing some more information.

Comment: Yes I think I can do that let me just post my concept I hope you can edit it further @john. Thanks

Comment: @john I think this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492814/Relative-design-components-on-WinForm) can also be useful but if I can find this much information the question was not properly researched I guess